# How to block ApacheBench from sending requests to server?

Tags: apache-2.4, ddos

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, Apache 2.4.
My server is under a huge DDoS attack right now, I tried to use mod_security , fail2ban and blocking attacking IPs manually using `iptables` and nothing worked.

The attackers are using "ApacheBench/2.3" to attack my apache2 server, they are sending huge requests to it, so is there anyway to block this tool and preventing it from sending requests to me?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "nothing worked"?  You can use those tools to block requests from `ab` - did you try to configure them to block and the attackers evaded the blocks, or the requests didn't get blocked by the configurations you tried?

Comment: Why didn't it work with iptables? Are they using more than one IP?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I installed fail2ban and turned on apache_overload and the other modules, this should have banned all the new IPs they use automatically, but nothing happened.

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin Yes, they are using more than 1 IP, everytime i block their IPs, they use a new one to attack me.

Comment: @MHS Then it's likely the rate limiting tools were not configured and working correctly, you should work to determine what's broken there and try to get the tools working correctly.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Well, the problem is that i didn't know how to block ApacheBench using one of these tools, do you have any URL for a page that explains this or something?

Comment: @MHS Understood!  This should get you started: http://serverfault.com/questions/251988/blocking-apache-access-via-user-agent-string

Comment: ApacheBench does the same as every other HTTP client. It is just optimized to measure the connections and reconnect fast. So blocking ApacheBench is like blocking any other client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I've received on the question, I have managed to solve the problem, you just have to edit the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file (or any other conf file you use, depending on your case) and make sure it looks like this:

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ApacheBench/2.3" bad_bot
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Deny from env=bad_bot
    </Directory>
```

Save the file and exit, and run:

```
 sudo service apache2 reload
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that's it !